# Why if i enqueue the tinymce script i get undefined error

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: random plug
Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
Version: 1.0
Author: Brad Williams
Author URI: http://wrox.com
License: GPLv2
*/

add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

 function register_tagging_post(){
       $tagging_args = array(
           'public' => true,
           'supports' => array(
               'title',
               'thumbnail'

           ), 
           'query_var' => 'tagging',
           'rewrite' => array(
              'slug' => 'tagging',
              'with_front' => false
           ),
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Tagge Albums',
            'singular_name' => 'Album',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
            'new_item' => 'New Album',
            'view_item' => 'View Album',
            'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
            'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
        ),

       );

       register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);

        wp_enqueue_script('tinymce123','http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js');


 }

?>
```

This is my plugin created, I want to ask why the firebug produced an error:

```
TypeError: tinymce.onAddEditor is undefined
```

when i enqueue the tinymce script and it is not functioning?

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you init the function to get the script to be workable, I think is not the correct way of enqueue the script. Try this below one and let me know if it all works fine. . .

```
    <?php 
        /*
        Plugin Name: random plug
        Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
        Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
        Version: 1.0
        Author: Brad Williams
        Author URI: http://wrox.com
        License: GPLv2
        */

        add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

         function register_tagging_post(){
               $tagging_args = array(
                   'public' => true,
                   'supports' => array(
                       'title',
                       'thumbnail'

                   ), 
                   'query_var' => 'tagging',
                   'rewrite' => array(
                      'slug' => 'tagging',
                      'with_front' => false
                   ),
                    'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'Tagge Albums',
                    'singular_name' => 'Album',
                    'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
                    'new_item' => 'New Album',
                    'view_item' => 'View Album',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
                    'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
                ),

               );

               register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);



         }
function register_tinymce_script() {
wp_register_script( 'tinymce123', 'http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js' );
wp_enqueue_script('tinymce123');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','register_tinymce_script');

        ?>
```